# Paginate database output from back to front - Laravel

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, laravel-blade

so I have a this in a controller

```
public function new_function(){
        $messages = Message::where('condition','=', 1)->paginate(20);
        return View::make('folder.template')->with(array('messages' => $messages ));
    }
```

And it outputs to a blade template that is something like this

```
@foreach($messages as $message)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ $message->created_at }}</td>
                                <td><a href="#">{{ $message->message_id }}</a></td>
                                <td>{{ $message->name }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $message->phone }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $message->email }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $message->message }}</td> 
                            </tr>
@endforeach
```

When it outputs, the latest entries into the DB are on the last page, which is very annoying. Is there any way I can get it to output so the newest messages output first on the page and the oldest ones on the last page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query results need to be **ordered** by **`desc`ending** order of when they were created, e.g.:

```
$messages = Message::where('condition','=', 1)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(20);
```

so that you get the last result first.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find this in the docs. I guess this has more to do database queries than pagination.

Comment: @JoeCo: You are welcome! Yes, it's really about the query. Take a look at [this documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#selects). Also, there's a very comprehensive [cheat sheet](http://cheats.jesse-obrien.ca/) that you may want to be aware of (you can even download it in pdf format).

Answer (score 0):

You have to order you results by date of creation, in reversed order:

```
$messages = Message::where('condition','=', 1)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(20);
```